# Does the phrase "a forward step" make any sense?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, word-order

I know "*a step forward*" means improvement.

But I want to use a phrase in the tagline of my blog.

Currently it is: A forward step to share drawings and useful content.

I just want to convey a message that "I have taken the responsibility to share the content for others". So is "*A forward step*" correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"A step forward" is a figurative expression meaning "progress" or "improvement", as you say. For example:

> This change of policy is a step forward.
>
> We need to take a step forward and eliminate these outmoded
>   regulations.

This would be OK:

> So that the community may take a step forward, I am
>   sharing drawings and content...

as would this:

> I am taking a step forward and sharing...

You could call it "a forward step" if you like. The order of the words is not critical there, although "step forward" is the collocation so your version would be a twist on the idiom.

However, "A forward step to share the content for others"  is only a *fragment* of the idea you wish to convey. The phrase lacks an explicit predicate.  It also lacks an agent, that which performs an action, or a subject about which some predication is made. So you also need a noun-phrase. Who is taking the step forward, or what thing is being called a step forward?

You can use a *to*-phrase nominally:

> To share drawings and content would be a step forward.

That can also be rephrased using so-called "dummy (or expletive) *it*":

> It would be a step forward to share drawings and content.